# Alter an already published build

Tags: artifactory

Is there a way to alter a build using the CLI after having published it?

UseCase: A deployer (be it automated or manual) wants to add additional files (e.g. Testresult-logs) to an already published build (because they need very long to be created but the artifacts of the fresh build should be published asap).

When I redo a `jfrog rt bp` over and over again I get "new" builds with the same description (same buildnumer etc.) instead of overwriting/extending existing build.

Appreciating any hint :-)

Answer (score 2):

The main idea of the buildinfo in Artifactory is that they are immutable, which means they cannot be modified post publish. This is to make sure the integrity of them.

In your case, a possible way to achieve this may be:
When publishing the artifacts themselves, you might want to not publish the buildinfo.
You can collect buildinfo through your build cycle, and publish everything as a single buildinfo object after all the tests.

Comment: Ariel, Thanx a lot for your fast reply! I kind of was anticipating that "immutable" strategy. Makes sense, of course.
Still, that idea of "after-everything-is-done" buildpublishing might be a solution. So the idea would be to upload all artefacts as soon as they are available with `--build-name` and `--build-number` parameters and then - when the last artifact got done - I do the `jfrog rt bp` for _that_ build-name and build-number, right? That would make the artifacts search- and filter-able by that build, even if the build itself is not listed, yet. Is that what you're saying?